# How to count objects using a ManyToManyField relationship in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

My **models.py** are like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='article_tags')
```

Lets say, I have a tag wit the name 'Movie Review', how do I get the number of articles that has a relationship with this tag? As in the count.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to get the articles that are using a specific tag (`your_tag` in the examples below):

- Either using a filtering on `Article`: `Article.objects.filter(tags=your_tag)`
- Or using the related relation: `your_tag.article_tags.all()`

Once you did that, you can just use [`.count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) to get the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Django's [`.count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count).

```
tag = Tag.objects.get(name='Movie Review')
article_count = tag.article_tags.all().count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query..

```
Article.objects.filter(tags__name='Movie Review')
```

to get the count

```
Article.objects.filter(tags__name='Movie Review').count()
```